# How do I create custom representations of my Type's in the right hand bar of an Xcode Playground?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-playground

How do I create custom representations of my type's in the right hand bar of an Xcode Playground? 
Is there some protocol to conform to? I've tried CustomStringConvertible.

Right now my struct values look like this in the playground:

```
{rawValue 10}
{{…}, {…}}
{{…}, {…}}
```

That's not very helpful...

Comment: Have you seen this page from the Apple docs? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/customplaygrounddisplayconvertible

Comment: Gracias.  I'll look into CustomPlaygroundDisplayConvertible

Comment: I also just noticed that the right hand bar takes CustomDebugStringConvertible for it's inline display if the type doesn't implement the CustomPlayground... protocol. That's only the inline display though. If the type conforms to the CustomPlayground... protocol then that replaces both the inline and the popup displays. Thanks again nteiss

Comment: @JustinMilo You should post that as a proper answer below.

Answer (score 0):

As @nteiss mentioned in the comments the key is `CustomPlaygroundDisplayConvertible`. Implementing this protocol will provide both in line and custom pop up displays in Playgrounds.

The [docs are here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/customplaygrounddisplayconvertible).

And the Swift evolution proposal that implemented this api also provides some more context: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0198-playground-quicklook-api-revamp.md

As an additional note, I also noticed that playgrounds will take `CustomDebugStringConvertible` for its inline display if the type doesn't implement the `CustomPlaygroundDisplayConvertible` protocol. That's only the inline display though. If the type conforms to the `CustomPlaygroundDisplayConvertible` protocol then that replaces both the inline and the popup displays.